# Rule violated for bundle java-gradle-examples: lines covered ratio is 0.0, but expected minimum is 0.5

Tags: java, gradle

** I'm learning and I write some simple tests, just to know how it works.
When I want to build a Gradle project I had this issue:
**Rule violated for bundle java-gradle-examples: lines covered ratio is 0.0, but expected minimum is 0.5**

Can anyone want to help me?**

**GRADLE.BUILD:**
`code`

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'}

group = 'pl.something'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '16'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.6'
}


dependencies {

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'

    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version:'5.0.0-M4'}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "skipped", "failed"
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = false
        csv.required = false
        html.outputLocation = layout.buildDirectory.dir('jacocoReports')
    }
}
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                value = 'COVEREDRATIO'
                minimum = 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

**My Test Class :**
`code`

```
    @Test
     void add() {
        int left = 2;
        int right = 1;
        int expected = 3;

        Integer result = left + right;
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    @Test
    void subtract() {
        int left = 2;
        int right = 1;
        int expected = 1;

        Integer result = left - right;
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    @Test
    void multiply() {
        int left = 2;
        int right = 1;
        int expected = 2;

        Integer result = left * right;
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    @Test
    @Disabled("I disabled this test for example")
    void divide() {
        int left = 2;
        int right = 1;
        int expected = 2;

        Integer result = left / right;
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

**And my Main.class:**
`code`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Calculator.add(1, 2));
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        Calculator.substract(5, 3);

    }

}
```